# My Python for loop executes 5005 times but it is meant to execute 100 times

Tags: python, ranged-loops

My output is 5005 serial numbers but i only  want 100.
currently it writes 5005 serial numbers to a file i want it to write 100 serial numbers.this program will be used to generate serial numbers to make a mostly secure login in another script please help :)

```
#!/usr/bin/python


#========Import Section========#
import random, hashlib, os
from sys import exit
from time import sleep
#========End Imports===========#
#====File paths for output=====#
database_check1 = os.path.expanduser('~/Codemaker/database.txt')
codemaker_dir_check1 = os.path.expanduser('~/Codemaker')
database_check = os.path.isfile(database_check1)
codemaker_dir_check = os.path.isdir(codemaker_dir_check1)
#====End File paths for output====#
#user import to ask if they would like to replace the file, quit or append more serial numbers to the database#
if codemaker_dir_check == True:
    pass
else:
    os.system('mkdir ~/Codemaker')

def choice():

    if database_check == True:
        replace_or_no = raw_input('Warning database.txt already exists do you want to relace it? y = yes n=no a = add more to end of file. y/n/a?: ')
        if replace_or_no == ('y'):
            os.system('rm ~/Codemaker/database.txt')
            os.system('> ~/Codemaker/database.txt')              

        elif replace_or_no == ('a'):
            pass
        elif replace_or_no == ('n'):
            print('We did not change the database :)')
            exit()

        else:
            print('An error has occured you probably pressed the wrong button if you wish to try again it should work')
            exit()
    else:
        os.system('> ~/Codemaker/database.txt')
#=============End user input==============# 
#=======Start variables=======#
Acceptable_letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890'
gencodelist = []
#=======End variables=======#
#=======Execute CLI======#
choice()
#=======End CLI======#
#=======path to database.txt=======#
database_file_append1 = os.path.expanduser('~/Codemaker/database.txt')
database_file_append = open(database_file_append1, 'a')
#=======End path to database.txt=======#


#=======Generate Serial Number========#
def gencode():
    for i in ('hih'):
        for i in ('hihi'):
            gencodelist.append(random.choice(Acceptable_letters))

        gencodelist.append('-')
    for i in ('hihi'):
        gencodelist.append(random.choice(Acceptable_letters))

    gencodelist.append('\n')
#======End Generate serial numbers======#
#=====write different serial numbers to file 100 times but it prints 5005 not what i want========#
for i in range(1, 100):
    gencode()
    gencodeout = ''.join(gencodelist)
    print(gencodeout)
    database_file_append.write(gencodeout)
#======End Write different serial numbers======#
#=====start end message=========#
message = ['100 codes have generated and been written to database.txt located in ', database_file_append1, '! :)']
finalmessage = "".join(message)
print(finalmessage)
#=====End end message=======#
```

Comment: Dumping your code without any effort explaining it, or narrowing where the bugs come from, is probably not going to lead to many answers...

Comment: I assume you are counting the lines in the file you write to. if so then this is not correct because you append to the file instead of overwriting. It also appears that you never close the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's simplify your program to understand how to get 5005 results:

```
gencodelist = []
for i in range(1, 100):
  gencodelist.append(str(i) + ' ')
  gencodeout = ''.join(gencodelist)
  print(gencodeout)
```

Here we are adding elements to the list `gencodelist` 99 times (from 1 to 99), and print all elements of this list each time. So, we have `1 + 2 + ... + 99` numbers in the output (it fact it is 4950, not your number 5005).

So, the problem is simple: you do not clear `gencodelist` in the very beginning of the function `gencode()`.